How to connect AWS Amplify and EC2?
I am very new with AWS and it is my first time to deploy my front-end app and back-end app on AWS.
So far, I have deployed my front-end on Amplify and I created instance on EC2 as well, I have installed java jdk as well. Now my question is what is my next step? How can I connect my Amplify and EC2?
I really want to deploy my service on AWS by end of April.
Front-end: React
Back-end: Springboot
DB: None (I don't need it)
